# Send audio to all outputs with individual level control

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers, headphones

I have some head phones hooked up to the front jack and some speakers hooked to the rear. In the Realtek Audio Manager I disabled front panel jack detection so I get sound out of both. However I would like to control the volume for the headphones independently of the speakers.

Any ideas how one could accomplish this?

One idea was to uninstall the realtek driver and use the microsoft one. That didn't work very well. It made the audio outputs mutually exclusive to one application.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have individual volume control in the Audio Manager?

Comment: @wiz3kid - Positive.